# Cannot install underscore using bower in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, underscore.js, visual-studio-2017, bower

Someone else asked the same question but didn't include the error and there wasn't any accepted answer, so I will try again.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I am following a course on Pluralsight about building a ASP.NET Core Web Application. The instructor wants use to install the underscore package using Bower.

I have tried adding it manually through the bower.json file and through the Manage Bower Packages gui but I am getting the this same error.

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install underscore#1.8.3 --force-latest --save
>   bower underscore#1.8.3      not-cached https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#1.8.3
>   bower underscore#1.8.3         resolve https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#1.8.3
>   bower underscore#1.8.3         ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git", exit code of #128

Here is my bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  }
}
```

I thought it might be an issue with git so I tried reinstalling but that didn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the above issue was a bug in Visual Studio 2017. I was able to resolve it by updating to the latest version which is currently 15.3.

After updating, bower worked fine for me.